# how to upload a file to attachment in salesforce using lightning?

Tags: lightning

This is the helper class in lightning:

```
({
        MAX_FILE_SIZE: 750 000,
        save: function(component) {
            var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement();
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            var fr = new FileReader();
            -- --some logic-- --
        })
```

from component I am calling this save method but I am getting this error:

> "Something has gone wrong. Action failed: c$fileUpload$controller$save [TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined]
>   Failing descriptor: {c$fileUpload$controller$save}.
>   Please try again."

Comment: Can you post your VF code aswell?

Comment: I have done it in develper console...lightning app,component,apex class,controller.js,helper class

Comment: Can you post the code for the component?

Comment: I posted it in another question@Frederik Witte

Comment: You need to post the code in this question not a separate question. You are able to edit your own question.